# Solving an inequality with many parameters

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation, inequalities

I need to solve the below inequality for `x`. I am very new to Mathematica. Below syntax does not give me any output. Please help.

```
Reduce[E^[(2 b - T) (x μ - λ)] <= β - (2 a β λ)/(x ν) + (2 a β μ)/ν, x]
```

Comment: First, syntax is wrong. You can't write `E^[]`. May be it was cut/paste error. Second, do you know any assumptions on the parameters? Assumptions can help find solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax should be either

```
Reduce[Exp[(2 b - T) (x μ - λ)] <= β - (2 a β λ)/(x ν) + (2 a β μ)/ν, x, Reals]
```

or

```
Reduce[E^((2 b - T) (x μ - λ)) <= β - (2 a β λ)/(x ν) + (2 a β μ)/ν, x, Reals]
```

But Mathematica can't solve this inequality without more information concerning the parameters. When you evaluate either you will get

> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I have below assumptions on parameters: a<0, 2b-T<0, x μ - λ>0, x>0, actually I need to derive x algebraically, as my theoretical result. Then I can apply appropriate numerical values to all others to find x in my simulations. So isn't there anyway that I can solve this inequality using above information and derive x algebraically?

Answer (score 1):

There is no algebraic solution for x with that inequation. But may be the folowing procedure helps you.

According to the given conditions, Exp[...] ranges between 0 and 1 and therefore the right side of the equation is greater zero.

So get condtions for the parameters to satisfy at least.

```
red = Reduce[
      0 < β - (2 a β λ)/(x ν) + (2 a β \
      μ)/ν && x μ - λ > 0 && x > 0 && a < 0, x, Reals] //
     LogicalExpand
```

You get 16 different sets of parameter conditions, for example

```
red[[4]]= (-(ν/(2 μ)) == a && 
           x > λ/μ && β > 0 && λ > 0 && μ > 
           0 && ν > 0)
```

Now insert definite values for the parameters to get exact condition for x

```
Manipulate[
   Reduce[Rationalize[
Exp[tbT (x μ - λ)] <= β - (2 a β \
λ)/(x ν) + (2 a β μ)/ν && (x > λ/\
μ && β > 0 && λ > 0 && μ > 0 && ν > 0) /. 
 a -> -(ν/(2 μ)), 0], x] // N, {ν, 1, 5}, {β, 1,
 6}, {λ, 1, 4}, {μ, 1, 6}, {tbT, -1, -5}, 
 ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]